# Lost passport in Qatar to be replaced in the Philippines. How to go back to Qatar?

Tags: passports

I am a Filipino in Qatar. I lost my passport in Qatar but I  need to travel back to Philippines for personal reasons. The Embassy will provide a Travel Document in lieu of the lost passport with police report in Qatar, and an affidavit of loss attached to the travel document. Then, I will process the new passport in the Philippines, as it will only take 10 days maximum unlike in Qatar.

Will I have a problem coming back to Qatar, since in my residence permit has the details of my lost passport and not of my new passport?

Comment: You should really be asking this question to the Qatar authorities, not us.

Comment: You cannot travel to Qatar, unless you can show proof that you are admissible in Qatar; further I do not recommend you travel on your emergency travel document without getting your residency transferred to a new passport. You should ask the Qatar Embassy in Philippines _before you travel_ if they can stamp a visa there for you on your new passport. Otherwise, you may have a hard time getting back to Qatar.

Comment: @stephanbranczyk this seems to be a valid question for this site. The asker could _also_ ask a state authority, but that's true for many questions on here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not ask for a replacement from the Philippine Embassy in Qatar? This seems to be the proper course of action in other countries.